How to process package options conditionally?
I need to pass an optional parameter value to a package as follows:
\usepackage[parameter=val]{mypkg}.
This value needs to be processed conditionally through the \DeclareOptionX{}{} command under the xkeyval package as follows:
\DeclareOptionX{parameter}{
    If(parameter=x) execute \xcmd
    Else            execute \ycmd
}

How the above, i.e. the \DeclareOptionX{}{} command, needs to be coded?

Have you read the document "LATEX for package and class authors
current version"?

Don't use xkeyval for new packages. Instead use either the built in mechanism (ltkeys) or expkv-opt (disclaimer: I'm the author of expkv-opt), or if you're using KOMA as a basis scrbase's options mechanism.
With that out of the way the following demonstrates how to achieve this with both ltkeys and expkv-opt:
expkv-opt
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
\ProvidesFile{\@currname}

\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}
\ekvdefinekeys{\@currname}
  {
     choice parameter = { x = \xcmd }
    ,unknown-choice parameter = \ycmd
  }

\newcommand\xcmd{\typeout{XCMD was called}}
\newcommand\ycmd{\typeout{YCMD was called}}

\ekvoProcessOptions{\@currname}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[parameter=x,parameter=val]{\jobname}

\stop

ltkeys
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
\ProvidesFile{\@currname}

\DeclareKeys
  {
     parameter .choice:
    ,parameter/x .code:n = \xcmd
    ,parameter/unknown .code:n = \ycmd
  }

\newcommand\xcmd{\typeout{XCMD was called}}
\newcommand\ycmd{\typeout{YCMD was called}}

\ProcessKeyOptions
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[parameter=x,parameter=val]{\jobname}

\stop


Both print to the terminal:
XCMD was called                                                                                                                                                                                                     
YCMD was called


[Nadolig llawen.]
